# MVC 5 Razor reload current view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

Is there any way to reload the current razor view by clicking on a link, without having to tell it the controller and action?

If I have a link on the Home/Index View, with the Home controller, I can do something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("some name", "Index", "Home")
```

But, if I want to have a link in the _Layout.cshtml that will be visible on all pages, I need something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("some name", default action of the current view, current controller, some parameter)
```

It probably can not be done with the actionlink, but is there some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why are you writing this as comment and not as answer if it is an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can provide `null` for the controller, action and route value arguments which will default to the current values.

For example if you have the following method in `ProductsController`

```
public ActionLink Details(int id)
```

and navigated to that url with `../Products/Details/2`, then the following link in that page or its layout

```
@Html.ActionLink("Refresh Page", null, null, null)
```

will generate the same url, i.e. `../Products/Details/2`

Note this works for route values (matching your route definitions), but will not add query string values